# Saving last array before quitting

Tags: ios, xcode, arrays, image, uiscrollview

I have an application which have UIScrollView with Paging .. and it has arrays with images .. What I want to do is saving which array has been viewed last time the app was running and when I open the app again it should show the last array has been viewed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tie your array saving code to the `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` notification, and then tie your loading code to the `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` notification.

You can also use the appropriate protocol methods in UIApplicationDelegate.

...rereading the question -- are you looking for help on how to save something or how to trigger saving at the right time?

*Edit*

It looks like you're already following a tutorial with Ray Wenderlich, but I'll just make a plug for one that I found incredibly simple when I was starting out: http://cocoadevcentral.com/

In terms of saving things to disk, you've got several options, the easiest of which is probably to use the NSUserDefaults as another user noted. It's a dictionary (key : value) system, so you can store your array/image/pathToTheImage, etc. by a name of your choosing, i.e.

"LastImageViewed" : UIImage <--(object) and then load it back by the same name.

```
 // MyAppDelegate.m
 - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

      // Save
      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:YOUR_ARRAY_GOES_HERE forKey:@"A_NAME_YOU_CHOOSE"];
      [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

 }

 ...

 - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {

      // Load
      NSArray *firstArrayToOpen = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"THE_NAME_YOU_CHOSE"];

      // Do your thing...
 }
```

Here's the reference for the NSUserDefaults class: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html

and the above mentioned notifications and methods reference: 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIApplicationDelegate

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks for replying @Miles Alden .. Actually I'm beginner in iOS development at all .. What I want to do is saving the array before quitting and when I open the app again it should view the same array .. please post a specific answer about this if you know the answer :)

Comment: hmmm .. I've understood your answer ... but keep in mind that I'm very beginner in development and programming ... It seems that you've noticed the tutorial I followed .. May you PLEASE show me the codes I should type ? :) thank you so much for your neat and specific answer :)

Comment: Hey Mohammed. I went ahead and put some specific lines in there that you can use/adapt. I can't stress enough though to study the docs yourself. Here's an app for easily navigating through lots of code docs as well: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dash-docs-snippets/id458034879?mt=12   Happy coding!

Comment: Hey Miles .. Thank you so much for your interest :) ... I've copied your codes to my project but I get an error : http://i.imgur.com/GItmt.jpg?1 ... I've downloaded dash it has a lot of docs (Y) which I'll study .. Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: It's probably a little clearer if you read the lines literally. I'll update it a little.

Comment: again :( http://i.imgur.com/QVhaU.png?1 .. may you can review you the tutorial and give me the right array ? please ? :)

Comment: Hey, let's wrap this up with a chat. I'll be here for the next few hours: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19284/ios-beginners

Comment: I don't know how to thank you for your interest .. I'd give you all my reputations :D .. Sorry I was asleep .. I'll be here for you for the next 10 hours :D just let me know in a comment when you're available ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to save this information using `NSUserDefaults`. Here's a tutorial on how to use it: http://epiicdream.wordpress.com/2012/02/27/ios-sdk-savingretrieving-data-using-nsuserdefaults/

Comment: Thank you @BlackRider for replying .. I'm beginner in iOS development .. could you please post the exact codes because I can't fully understand the tutorial ? .. Thank you :)

Comment: Take a look at the tutorial I linked to, it has the actual code samples. I can't write the code for you because I don't have your existing code.

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content

starting from "Paging with UIScrollView" is EXACTLY my codes ... Thanks in advance :)